# How to add dynamic action items to android BottomSheet?

Tags: android, material-design, bottom-sheet

I am developing an app that would implement a `BottomSheet` like Google material design one. All I found is a static actions that can be added to the Sheet, like this using this library [BottomSheet](https://github.com/soarcn/BottomSheet):

```
new BottomSheet.Builder(this).title("title").sheet(R.menu.list).listener(new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        switch (which) {
                            case R.id.help:
                                q.toast("Help me!");
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }).show();
```

Here, `R.menu.list` loads static actions into the `BottomSheet`.
What I wanted is to add dynamic action items to it, for example, an `ArrayList` of actions. Any idea?

Btw, I tried to add this tag "bottom-sheet" to my question, but I don't have privileges for that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it with .sheet() method:

```
BottomSheet bottomSheet = new BottomSheet.Builder(getActivity())
                    .title(R.string.sharing_warning_note)
                    .sheet(R.id.menu_facebook, facebookDrawable,
                            getString(R.string.publishing_settings_facebook))
                    .sheet(R.id.menu_vkontakte, vkontakteDrawable,
                            getString(R.string.publishing_settings_vkontakte))
                    .divider()
                    .listener(new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            switch (which) {
                                case R.id.menu_facebook:
                                    share(SocialNetworkType.FACEBOOK);
                                    break;
                                case R.id.menu_vkontakte:
                                    share(SocialNetworkType.VK);
                                    break;
                                default:
                            }
                        }
                    })
                    .build();
            bottomSheet.show();
```

-UPDATE-

with array list you can like this:

```
BottomSheet bottomSheet = new BottomSheet.Builder(getActivity());
for (int i = 0; i<list.size(); i++) {
     String s = list.get(i);
     bottomSheet.sheet(i, null, s);
}
bottomSheet.build();
bottomSheet.show();
```

Comment: At last, these menu items are static. I have an `ArrayList` of actions I need to load into the Sheet, this would not help ! I don't want the `R.id.someItem`. I need to load some sort of `ArrayList` into it.

Comment: it's not static, you can write like this:
.sheet(1, icon, "blabla")
in my case, id has declared in res/ids.xml, but it's not a menu.

Comment: Your solution uses existed resourceId, i.e. `R.id.menu_facebook` but I don't want that. Isn't there any idea to do like this: `sheet(new ArrayList)` ? or something similar?

Comment: Instead of using existed ids, you can use any positive integers. I've updated my answer with ArrayList of Strings.

Comment: I am having similar issue, if I want to set visibility of menu items dynamically how can we achieve this.                                                        new BottomSheet.Builder(this)
                      .setSheet(R.menu.menu_items)
                      .grid()
                      .setTitle("Menu")
                      .setListener(this)
                      .show();